# conditionally process items in mongodb group (aggregation pipeline)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider a MongoDB collection with survey results, where the results are either of type *feedback* (arbitary amount of free-text answers) or *multi* (user may select all, none or some of a provided set of answers). All questions have a unique name, and the type and set of answers stays consistent for that particular name.

Consider this set of example entries:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("572c4af25e30ae25a0307df0"), 
    "question" : "Q1", 
    "type" : "feedback", 
    "answers" : [
        "feedback value 1", 
        "feedback value 2"
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("572c4b7a5e30ae25a0307dfa"), 
    "question" : "Q1", 
    "type" : "feedback", 
    "answers" : [
        "feedback value 2"
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("572c4b885e30ae25a0307dfc"), 
    "question" : "Q2", 
    "type" : "feedback", 
    "answers" : [
        "feedback value 1"
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("572c4ba65e30ae25a0307dfe"), 
    "question" : "Q3", 
    "type" : "multi", 
    "answers" : [
        {
            "value" : "A1", 
            "chosen" : true
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "A2", 
            "chosen" : false
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("572c4c125e30ae25a0307e00"), 
    "question" : "Q3", 
    "type" : "multi", 
    "answers" : [
        {
            "value" : "A1", 
            "chosen" : false
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "A2", 
            "chosen" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want is to create some kind of *evaluation aggregation*, where thhe result should look like this (one resulting document for each answer):

```
{
  "_id": "Q1",
  "type:" "feedback",
  // list of _unique_ values
  "answers": ["feedback value 1", "feedback value 2"]
}
// Q2 omitted for the sake of shortness
{
  "_id": "Q3",
  "type:" "multi",
  // list of all answers with selection count, including the never-chosen ones
  "answers": {
     "A1": 1,
     "A2": 0 
  }
}
```

So how can I create such an aggregation? I first thought of map-reduce, but as everyone says one should prefer the aggregation pipeline, I gave that a try.

My first step was to group by the question id ("question" field). I then wanted to add to additional fields in the group phase that correspond to the answer type of *feedback* and *multi* surveys. Another "projection" phase should then select the proper field for the output.

```
db.survey.aggregate(
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$question",
                type: {
                    $first: "$type"
                },
                answersFeedback: {
                    // this creates nested arrays 
                    // instead of an array of strings
                    $addToSet: {
                        $cond: [{
                            $eq: ["$type", "feedback"]
                        }, "$answers", []]
                    }
                },
                // no idea how to achieve this
                answersMulti: {
                    $first: {
                        $literal: {
                            "foo": 42
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $project: {
                "type": 1,
                // select answer field according to type
                "answers": {
                    $cond: [{
                        $eq: ["$type", "multi"]
                    }, "$answersMulti", "$answersFeedback"]
                }
            }
        }

    ]
);
```

Unfortunately the feedback answer results in nested arrays

```
{ 
    "_id" : "Q2", 
    "type" : "feedback", 
    "answers" : [
        [
            "feedback value 1"
        ]
    ]
}
```

and I have no clue how to process the multi votes. Can you please help me to go on?

The database runs on a v3.2.4 server. The used schema (data format) is a simplified version of the actual data, and I may not modify it, I do really have  to work on that as-is.

Comment: Just a quick thought, if you don't want the nested results have you tried the unwind command to split out the answer array

Comment: @iestync yes, thank you, haven't though of that. It solves my *feedback* problem, but I still have no clue how to relaize the *multi* part..

Comment: Sorry I missed that part, maybe if you unwind the answers array early on in the pipeline then you could use project to collect the values, are the values predictable ? e.g. always A1,A2

Comment: I think you should run two different queries and merge the result client-side. Also I see that `if type === 'multi'` you want to use your data as *key* which is not possible with the aggregation framework unless you know all the possibles value i.e `A1, A2`